# Machine Learning - Changes Over Time and Relationship To Inputs

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

Is there a machine learning algorithm that looks at the change of inputs in relation to each other over time?

I apologize for being a bit out of my depth here.  I'm hoping for a solution that gives the probability and can be built in either MSSQL Analysis Services or Accord.NET.

Right now I have 10 inputs and 1 prediction that have been discretized (quantile, 10 buckets).  For example:

- Given any $x_1$ through $x_{10}$, there is an equal probability of $y_1$ through $y_{10}$
- If ($x_1 = 5$ and $x_2 = 0$) or ($x_1 = 9$ and $x_2 = 4$), then there is an equal probability of it being in $y_2$ through $y_9$.
- If over time, ($x_1$ increases) and ($x_2$ decreases) and ($x_3$ is unchanged),  then there is a 90% probability of $y_7$.

Comment: If you replace the red herring "machine learning" and replace it with "statistics" you'll find yourself in the world of *time-series modeling.* Quantile buckets will decrease model power, though.